# How to parse large XML files with xpaths?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I wrote the code for parsing (reading) an XML file and inserting the attributes into an Excel sheet. I am using the `XmlDocument` class to read the XML file.

This works well if the XML is small, but if the XML is very large, then it is not able to process that large of an XML file.

How can I parse large XML files with xpath combination?

Comment: _it not able to processing that big xml_, please post the exception you are getting and the relevant part from your code where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `SelectNodes` to cut the xml document in small elements

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes(".....");
if (nodeList != null)
   {
       foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
```

Comment: can i use xmlreader insted of xmldocument for large xml files

Comment: @RavitejaChekuri I dont know how to use XMLReader instead of XMLDocument, but you can create the XMLDocument by loading an XMLReader into it

See this page for more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ta6tz4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to cut your XML to smaller part